# How To Use OAuth in My iPhone App?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, json, oauth

I'm trying to configure OAuth into my iPhone app to connect to another web service but I'm having problems with it.

I have downloaded the google gtm-oauth files and added them to my project.

```
- (GTMOAuthAuthentication *)myCustomAuth {
    NSString *myConsumerKey = @"2342343242";    // pre-registered with service
    NSString *myConsumerSecret = @"324234234242"; // pre-assigned by service

    GTMOAuthAuthentication *auth;
    auth = [[[GTMOAuthAuthentication alloc] initWithSignatureMethod:kGTMOAuthSignatureMethodHMAC_SHA1
                                                        consumerKey:myConsumerKey
                                                         privateKey:myConsumerSecret] autorelease];

    // setting the service name lets us inspect the auth object later to know
    // what service it is for
    auth.serviceProvider = @"RunKeeper";

    return auth;
}
- (void)signInToCustomService {

    NSURL *requestURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://runkeeper.com/apps/token"];
    NSURL *accessURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://runkeeper.com/apps/token"];
    NSURL *authorizeURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://runkeeper.com/apps/authorize"];
    NSString *scope = @"http://example.com/scope";

    GTMOAuthAuthentication *auth = [self myCustomAuth];

    // set the callback URL to which the site should redirect, and for which
    // the OAuth controller should look to determine when sign-in has
    // finished or been canceled
    //
    // This URL does not need to be for an actual web page
    [auth setCallback:@"http://www.example.com/OAuthCallback"];

    // Display the autentication view
    GTMOAuthViewControllerTouch *viewController;
    viewController = [[[GTMOAuthViewControllerTouch alloc] initWithScope:scope
                                                                language:nil
                                                         requestTokenURL:requestURL
                                                       authorizeTokenURL:authorizeURL
                                                          accessTokenURL:accessURL
                                                          authentication:auth
                                                          appServiceName:@"RunKeeper"
                                                                delegate:self
                                                        finishedSelector:@selector(viewController:finishedWithAuth:error:)] autorelease];

    [[self navigationController] pushViewController:viewController
                                           animated:YES];
}
```

This is the API I am trying to connect with: http://developer.runkeeper.com/healthgraph/registration-authorization

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, read up on oauth.  it's a bit different from your normal login/pw type auth.

Second, you can use Google's oauth library at http://code.google.com/p/gtm-oauth/

Comment: Ok, I downloaded all the relevant file and added them to a folder in my project, but now what do I do?