# How To Download gtm-oauth files?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, oauth

I am trying to add this library to my project but cant seem to figure how to download it.  I went to the source page and downloaded each file individually but they seem to be corrupt when i open them on my computer.

http://code.google.com/p/gtm-oauth/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To quote the source page which you have kindly linked to,

> # Non-members may check out a read-only working copy anonymously over HTTP.
>
> svn checkout http://gtm-oauth.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ gtm-oauth-read-only

Comment: Can you check this question out? Thanks. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6513363/how-to-use-oauth-in-my-iphone-app

Comment: @tc. I was trying to download from this link but it seems not a valid link now...can you please help me with this. Is there any alternate way to get it.